# 3d Engine Undefined errors

Tags: c++, 3d, drawing

There are multiple errors surrounding things being undefined, In my code.
I'm using Microsoft visual studio community 2019 with the Console project preset.
And am coding this in C++.

Here is the Code in question:

```
// Engine3D engine.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "Engine3D engine.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_ENGINE3DENGINE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ENGINE3DENGINE));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ENGINE3DENGINE));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_ENGINE3DENGINE);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // Draw a triangle
        POINT points[3] = { {50, 50}, {150, 50}, {100, 150} };
        Polygon(hdc, points, 3);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0; // Add this line to explicitly return 0 after processing WM_PAINT

    break;


    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Its in the WMPAINT area I'm pretty sure

I was expecting it to compile and draw the triangle, however it had multiple bugs that stopped it from compiling.

Here are the errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description     Project         File                                                                Line    Suppression State
Error       C2047   illegal default Engine3D engine C:\Users\My name\source\repos\Engine3D engine\Engine3D engine.cpp   166 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2046   illegal case    Engine3D engine C:\Users\\source\repos\Engine3D engine\Engine3D engine.cpp  162 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2043   illegal break   Engine3D engine C:\\\source\repos\Engine3D engine\Engine3D engine.cpp   161 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2043   illegal break   Engine3D engine C:\Users\seth\source\repos\Engine3D engine\Engine3D engine.cpp  164 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'ps': undeclared identifier Engine3D engine C:\Users\\source\repos\Engine3D engine\Engine3D engine.cpp  159 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ps" is undefined    Engine3D engine C:\Users\\source\repos\Engine3D engine\Engine3D engine.cpp  160 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0122   a default label may only be used within a switch    Engine3D engine C:\Users\\\repos\Engine3D engine\Engine3D engine.cpp    167 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0121   a case label may only be used within a switch   Engine3D engine C:\Users\\\repos\Engine3D engine\Engine3D engine.cpp    163 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0116   a break statement may only be used within a loop or switch  Engine3D engine C:\Users\\\repos\Engine3D engine\Engine3D engine.cpp    162 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0116   a break statement may only be used within a loop or switch  Engine3D engine C:\Users\\\repos\Engine3D engine\Engine3D engine.cpp    165
```

Comment: Look at the lines starting at `EndPaint`. That brace ends the switch and you can't have case or default outside the switch.

Comment: Can you possibly provide a code snippet or something else?

Comment: Side note: It's a lot less messy to copy from the Output tab usually found beside the Error List than from the Error List

Comment: At some point you will need to learn to read your own code and understand it. Today is a good opportunity for that. Start with line 162. You can click the error and it will take you right there. You have an extra `EndPaint` and `break` and then cases outside the switch.

Comment: To help you out, I've hit your code with an autoformatter to make the mistake Retired Ninja is pointing out stand out: https://godbolt.org/z/hr1xMsaWe

Comment: Mistakes often show up as irregularities in the code, so an experienced programmer's eyes are always drawn to weird-looking code. If you religiously follow an indentation style, looks like you are already mostly following Allman, you'll find whole families of mistakes become obvious. In this case the weird-looking code is the sudden deviation from Allman style in `WndProc`.

Comment: *"multiple errors surrounding things being undefined,"* -- The first error is "illegal default" not "undefined". Ignore the later errors until you understand the first one. It's not uncommon for later "errors" to be merely artifacts of earlier errors. *(I once resolved dozens of "errors" by adding a missing semicolon. There was only one real error, but it threw my compiler off, leading to it reporting many more.)*